# Probability permutation

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

In how many ways can $5$ identical oranges be distributed among $4$ identical baskets?

My solution:

$(5,0,0,0),
(4,1,0,0),
(3,2,0,0),
(3,1,1,0),
(2,2,1,0),
(2,1,1,1)$ so 6 ways

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin Although there is a bit of ambiguity, this question could also be about https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory) (with the restriction that there are at most 4 parts)

Comment: Since the objects are identical and the containers are also identical, this is the number of ways in which 5 can be expressed as a sum of at most 4 positive integers. If we denote the number of ways of writing $n$ as a sum of $k$ positive integers by $P(n,k)$, there is no closed form formula for $P(n,k)$ but there is a recurrence relation: $P(n,k) = P(n-1,k-1) + P(n-k, k)$. In this problem, you need $P(5,1) + P(5,2) + P(5,3) + P(5,4)$.

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek I meant the 2md question in [this revision](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/3714956/1), now it appears to be edited out, so you're perfectly right, it's partitions.